# Composer update, how do I resolve requirements?

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony2-easyadmin

On Symfony 2.3 and **using composer** trying to install a new bundleI get the following:

> Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
>   dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be
>   resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - The requested package doctrine/doctrine-bundle (locked at v1.2.0, required as ~1.4) is satisfiable by
>   doctrine/doctrine-bundle[v1.2.0] but these conflict with your
>   requirements or minimum-stability.   Problem 2
>       - The requested package doctrine/cache (locked at v1.3.0, required as ~1.6) is satisfiable by doctrine/cache[v1.3.0] but these conflict
>   with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
>   content.

How do I resolve these?

My json file:

```
"php": ">=5.3.3",
"symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
"doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
"doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
"doctrine/cache": "~1.6"
},
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us your `composer.json`? It looks like there is problem with `minimum-stability` line. Also try removing it.

Comment: Tomas I added the part of the json that shows the minimum-stability. What does this mean? I'm just taking over this fro previous dev

Comment: Thanks. It means if you use `stable` versions od `dev` versions (unstable). There is default value `"minimum-stability": "stable",` so you can delete it.

It looks like it is Symfony sandbox's `composer.json`. You can also leave `branch-alias` part. 

What happened after the removal?

Comment: @Tomas, my understanding is that by using "minimum-stability" requires all of the bundles to meet the minimums to be able to have an stable project, isn't this correct? So is forcing you to install stable bundles.

Comment: Yes, it is default value, so you can omit that line.

Comment: Nothing, I cannot install javiereguiluz/easyadmin-bundle, still getting Problems when installing

Comment: I just tried that manually and with no problem. Try deleting `composer.lock`.
Also providing full `composer.json` would still be helpful.
Also you can try bumping Symfony to `~2.3`

Comment: How did you try to install EasyAdminBundle?

Comment: Using $ composer require easyadmin-bundle -vvv and of course having issues with dependencies I had to "minimum-stability": "stable" and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to install packages that are not released yet if there is no stable release available by adding this just before the require section of your composer.json file:

```
// ...

"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.1.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
},

// ...
```

You have to remove the other minimum stability rule of course

Comment: Nothing. I still cannot install the bundle. The one I'm trying to install is javiereguiluz/easyadmin-bundle. I'm getting:  Problem 1
    - The requested package doctrine/doctrine-bundle (locked at v1.2.0, required as 1.4.*) is satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-bundle[v1.2.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - Conclusion: don't install javiereguiluz/easyadmin-bundle v1.16.1  Can only install one of: doctrine/cache[1.5.3, v1.3.0]. - Installation request for doctrine/cache (locked at v1.3.0) -> satisfiable by doctrine/cache[v1.3.0].